# Javascript return OR with assignment of value?

Tags: javascript, d3.js, return, or-operator

I'm working with a [simple example](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/2949937) in D3, and I've been puzzling over this return statement for a while.

```
function nodeByName(name) {
    return nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {name: name});
}
```

I have a basic understanding of using the `||` operator in a return statement, but please correct me if I'm wrong. From what I have gathered, if `nodesByNames[name]` is undefined, then a new object `nodesByName[name]` is created with a name of `name`.

What I'm trying to get at is that I don't know how to wrap my mind around returning an assignment like `nodesByName[name]={name:name}`.

Comment: An assignment is an *expression* in JavaScript. The result of the expression is the value that was assigned.

Comment: @Felix I thought that my wording was incorrect. What should I say instead to be more precise?

Comment: No it's fine. I just wanted to explain that since an assignment is an expression, in can be used everywhere where expressions are allowed and it has to return a value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use the `||` operator to create an expression (i.e. `a || b`), JavaScript will return either the *first* operand that evaluates to something truthy, like `1` or `true` or any object, or else will return the last value. (So `a || b || c` will return `c` if all of the values are false).

In your example, you have this:

```
nodesByName[name] || (nodesByName[name] = {name: name})
```

Javascript will start by evaluating the left hand side, `nodesByName[name]`. If this value is something truthy, it will be returned. If it is not, (and `undefined` is not), the right hand side will be evaluated and returned. The right hand side is an assignment, which will return an object, `{name: name}`, after assigning it to `nodesByName[name]`.

The reason for having this chunk of code is to assign a value to `nodesByName[name]` if it does not already have a value.

Comment: Also, "The competent programmer is fully aware of the strictly limited size of his own skull; therefore he approaches the programming task in full humility, and among other things he avoids clever tricks like the plague." -Edsger Dijkstra

Comment: I'm a little puzzled. Is the quote meant to indicate that this code is a clever trick that should be avoided?

Comment: Yes. Code like this can be tough to read, and can be done in a manner that's easy to read for anyone, using if statements.

Comment: Thank you, I needed your explanation in order to understand what these statements meant. Now I can go back and rewrite the code in a way that is more appropriate for the size of my skull.

Answer (score 1):

It's not returning an assignment, it's returning the return value of the assignment. See http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2008/01/using_the_assig.html for more info on the return value of `=`. In this case, when `nodesByName[name]` is undefined, the function will return `{name: name}` (which evaluates to `true` because all objects do).

Answer (score 0):

The code above would work only if your nodesByName object is always defined!

Here is the explanation of what you do not understand:

```
{name: name}
```

actually creates a new object with property 'name' set to the value of your name variable.

```
nodesByName[name] = {name: name} or nodesByName[name] = {our new object here}
```

Once this object is created it is assigned to the object nodesByName under the property with `name` of the passed name parameter.

Answer (score 0):

In the code you have posted `var nodesByName = {};` already declares your object.
So you're code is basically to be read like this:

- Does `nodesByName` already have an property of name `name`? then return it
- Create an object, only with a property `name` and set it to the given value in the parameter
- Assign the object as an property with the name to the nodesByName object
- Oh, and when you're done with that return the value as well

So return basically only returns the newly created object.

Trying to write the code another way:

```
function nodeByName(name) {
  if (nodesByName.hasOwnPropery(name)) {
    return nodesByName[name];
  }

  var newNode = {name: name};
  nodesByName[name] = newNode;
  return newNode;
}
```

Basically does the same thing, just uses more lines of code.

Comment: Not quite right. In the original code, if `nodesByName[name] === 0` (or null or false), the `||` operator will continue on to the second expression.

Comment: I can agree to that, but is that really the correct expected behavior? Also what about `nodesByName('toString')`? Would return a function in the original code.